# how to change keyboard layout from Spanish to English

Tags: linux

I installed a virtual linux machine using a existing vmdk which I got from an Spanish guy. after the installation, I found the keyboard layout is totally different from my laptop's keyboard, I guess it is because the default keyboard layout of this virtual Linux machine is Spanish, so my question is how to change the keyboard layout to the normal English layout.

Comment: after some google search, I found loadkeys us will serve my needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
setxkbmap us
```

Will change back to qwerty

There should be some other ways depending on your DE. On Xfce4 you can go to settings->keyboard->layout.